# make a form results show on same page where data comes from another site

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

Ok, I have a unique issue. I have a real estate wordpress website that uses IDX (Internet Data Exchange) data to show MLS (Multiple Listing Service) listings.  So all the IDX data is stored through my IDX provider's site.  Currently, when a user submits a form, it goes to a results page that is hosted through my idx provider (example: http://www.mysite.idxco.com/idx/my.account#/results.php?).  What I am trying to do is create a form which would render the results on the same page....how would I do that?  If I am not being clear enough please let me know.

Comment: Can you retrieve data directly from IDX (via an API call, for example) or is your access limited to posting HTML forms?

Comment: I'm not sure, George Cummins, I will have to ask the idx company if API calls are an option

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you have different options, you can

1) POST via ajax, and have your hosted page send back html in response that you can show in the same page in a div. Its very easy to do with jquery. It might be easier to integrate in a wordpress page, but you need to be able to modify your hosted page.

2) you can post to a page on your server (not on the idx provider's), then use curl to send the  data you received from your form as a post to the idx provider page, grab the returned html, parse it, get the results, reload the page with your own form along with the results you got from curl.

You might need to check with your idx provider if it is ok that you 'scrape' the data.

(Of course if you had a api access which is very likely with idx you can just send a api request, which would be much more efficient )

Comment: thnx, smarques, I am a little new at this stuff, I may just want to hire someone to do .....what u said ;)